# Spring jms buffer messages into a batch before processing and acknowledging

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms

I'm looking for an example of how to achieve the following with Spring jms.

My application receives messages from a queue and after some processing sends the result to a web service.  That web service now supports bulk messages and we'd like to start using it.  [The Client AcknowledgmentMode](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/JmsProperties.AcknowledgeMode.html) appears to be one piece of the puzzle but I don't yet understand how we can prevent messages piling up in memory in the application.  If the bulk api request or any processing of any of the messages leading up to it fail, all jms messages would have to be rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch provides a [BatchMessageListenerContainer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure-tests/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/container/jms/BatchMessageListenerContainer.java) for exactly this purpose.